# Java: get the number of seconds of a Calendar variable

Tags: java, calendar

I have a java.util.Calendar variable (like 2016-05-24 00:01:05.780) and I want to get the total of seconds of the time. In this example, I want to get 65 as result.

I tried to use myCalendarVariable.getTimeInMillis()/1000 but I got -2208977011 as result.

How can I do that?

Comment: So just to be clear, if you had 2016-05-24 01:01:05.780 you'd want the result to be 3665?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

`variable.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 * 60 + variable.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 + variable.get(Calendar.SECOND)`

Note that `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` is used when you're using a 24-hour clock, whereas `Calendar.HOUR` should be used for 12-hour clocks. In this situation you want to use the former.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourdate);
int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = minutes*60 + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use get function:

```
myCalendarVariable.get(HOUR_OF_DAY)* 3600 + myCalendarVariable.get(MINUTE) * 60 + myCalendarVariable.get(SECOND)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which scope of seconds you were looking for, so try one of these:

```
Calendar myCalendarVariable = Calendar.getInstance();
int secondsInHour = myCalendarVariable.get((Calendar.MINUTE) * 60) + myCalendarVariable.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int secondsOfDay = (myCalendarVariable.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 * 60) + secondsInHour;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your date into a `LocalDateTime` you can the seconds of day directly.

The convertion from `Calendar` to `LocalDateTime` has been omitted, as you might have the data in another format. This should be easy to amend to your needs.

```
LocalDateTime of = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 5, 24, 0, 1, 5, 780000000);
System.out.println("seconds of day: " + of.getLong(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY));
```

output

```
seconds of day: 65
```